# php errors with custom taxonomy page — WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have successfully created a custom taxonomy in WordPress, and I created a page that lists all of the posts under a specified taxonomy, with a file named `taxonomy.php`. It works, but some of the php isn't printing any text. The page seems to churn out some php errors with error reporting turned on:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: term_name in WEBSITE_ROOT/themes/starkers/taxonomy.php on line 24
```

The variable is `$term_name`. Here is the code I have in my `taxonomy.php` page. I followed [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/comment-page-1/#comments). I thought I followed the tutorial pretty well.

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>

            <h1><?php
                printf( __( 'Posts classified under: %s', 'starkers' ), '<span>' . $term_name . '</span>' );

            ?></h1>

            <?php
                $category_description = category_description();
                if ( ! empty( $category_description ) )
                    echo '' . $category_description . '';

            get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );
            ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Basically, it's not printing the taxonomy name after "Posts classified under:"

I tried fiddling around with the code, but no luck. If it helps, here is the code I used for `functions.php` to registering the taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy(
    'quotees',
    'post',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'label' => 'quotees',
        'query_var' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => true
    )
);
}
```

Comment: If you look in the comments, apparently `$term_name` should be `$term->name`. In fact, most of the `$term_blah`s should be `$term->blah`.

Comment: That seemed to do the job. I had to also wrap some of the code in `<?php ?>` in order for it to work though. They should update that article! You can answer this question and I'll accept it if you want the credit.

Comment: Could you edit those changes into your question (or just answer the question yourself, if you want)? Since the author of that post doesn't want to change his code, it's sort of misleading to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the comments, apparently `$term_name` should be `$term->name`. In fact, most of the `$term_blahs` should be `$term->blah`.